# how to get a view from view class?

Tags: android, view, android-activity

i am new developer in android.i have created a view class in that view class i would like to applay string array values to textview my View class is follows:

```
    class MyView extends View
 {
    Context con;
String messages[]=new String[]{"hello","hai","how are you","where are you"};
public MyView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    con=context; 

       for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
     {

         Log.v("messages", "messages"+messages[i]);
     }


     public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup vg)
{
    if (view == null)
    {
        // context would be a variable set via the constructor and given
        // by our owner (most likely a ListActivity)
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)con.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view, null);
    }

    // Here you would get the sub-views of your layout and fill them
    TextView msg = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtmessage);
    msg.setText(messages[position]);
    return view;
}
```

}

from the above class i would like view the view of MyView class in activity class

```
     public class ViewActivity extends Activity {



TableRow tbr;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view);

     tbr=(TableRow)findViewById(R.id.tableRow1);


     MyView mv=new MyView(this);
     tbr.addView(mv);

}
```

}

from the above code i am not able to view of MyView class

how can i get the view of MyView class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the layoutparams to your view. Right now your view has no size.

you need something like this

```
MyView mv=new MyView(this);
mv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT)));
tbr.addView(mv);
```